# how to write regular express for inserting at specific location?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have long file containing lines like :

```
Redirect 301 /abcdef/ /ab/page1
Redirect 301 /abcdefasdff/ /abaff/page2
```

I need to insert or replace the following place(refer to *) with my domain for all the lines

```
Redirect 301 /abcdef/ */ab/page1
Redirect 301 /abcdefasdff/ */abaff/page2
```

result:

```
Redirect 301 /abcdef/ https://exmaple.com/ab/page1
Redirect 301 /abcdefasdff/ https://example.com/abaff/page2
```

can I use editor find and replace function to do this ?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: thank you for the response , I have solved the problem

Comment: This is about how to use a text editor, it does not have anything to do with javascript, a regular expression or an http server's dynamic configuration...

Comment: you are right it's nothing to do with javascript , server ,but regular expression is concern

find -> Redirect 301 /([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /
replace -> Redirect 301 /$1 https://www.example.com/

Answer (score 0):

Simply search for "/ /" and replace it with "/ https://example.com/"

for missing first slash " /"

```
Find -> Redirect 301 /([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /
Replace -> Redirect 301 /$1 https://www.example.com/
```